# BASH kill wget if no response

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I have this code

`...

   SERVERCONNECTION=$(wget --quiet -O - http://xx:yy@127.0.0.1:10001/server | grep connections  | awk '{print $36}')`

Sometimes the url get inresponsive, then I want to kill wget process and set SERVERCONNECTIION variable to 0.

Comment: Googling for `bash alarm` seems to come up with some useful links, eg. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-scripting-run-command-under-alarmclock/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a timeout for the wget process with `--timeout=seconds`, i.e.

```
SERVERCONNECTION=$(wget --timeout=5 --quiet -O - http://xx:yy@127.0.0.1:10001/server | grep connections | awk '{print $36}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Another useless use of grep.

Use `awk '/connections/ {print $36}'` instead, so that the whole line reads

```
wget --timeout=5 --quiet -O - http://xx:yy@127.0.0.1:10001/server | awk '/connections/ {print $36}'
```

Comment: While your comment about `grep` is true, it rather masks the fact that you've _also_ answered the question. Perhaps you could edit your post to give the answer first, and then note about `grep`?